# SonarQube on reverse proxy in IIS refuses to execute script

Tags: iis, sonarqube, reverse-proxy, url-rewrite-module

I have Sonar Qube server running fine with Apache Tomcat, and a reverse proxy with URL Rewrite in IIS. The reverse proxy maps the domain name to the localhost:9000 address for Sonar Qube just fine, but the java script files embedded in the home page do not run. In Chrome's dev tools I get this error (company sensitive names have been made generic in this error output):

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://sonarqube.company.us/sonar/js/vendor.foo.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Refused to execute script from 'http://sonarqube.company.us/sonar/js/app.bar.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I've followed the instructions on this dev blog post to the letter to no avail (it's a 3 part series, part 3 addresses this specific problem): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-part-3-rewriting-the-outbound-response-contents/

Has anyone come up against this before and solved it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the setup of your reverse proxy is incorrect because the mimetypes of JavaScript files are incorrect.

Can you remove the configuration of overwriting the mime types ? 
The one sent by SonarQube should be preserved.

Comment: Hi Eric, Can you point me on how to remove the configuration of overwriting mime types? I run into this same issue, but can't find anything usable.